# trying to call python file inside other Python Program

Tags: python

How to call one python file from another python file

Example :

I have a file in `C:\Python\a1.py`

Now I am working on `a2.py` and want to call `a1.py` from `a2.py`. How can I achieve that?

Also is it mandatory both should be on same location to call other either programs?

Comment: Please specify **how** do you want to "call" your program. Do you want to run the script from another file or do you want to include this secondary file to your first file and use its functions and classes?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is confusing since you are not using Python terminology. Do you mean that you have some functions and code in module `a1` (which has the filename `a1.py`) and also in module `a2` (in `a2.py`), you are running `a2` and you want to call some routines that are in `a1`? If so, that is what the `import` statement is for. Please read [a Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), which is not the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `a1.py`:

```
import a2

...

a2.some_func()
```

where `some_func` is a function you defined in `a2.py`. If you want to be more specific you could even do

```
from a2 import some_func
...
some_func()
```

As for whether the two files need to be in the same place: yes. If they're not in the same place, then you need to account for the directory structure, (e.g. `import lib.a2` if `a2.py` is in a file called `lib`).

It's possible for two files to not be in the same place, but then the files need to be on the *pythonpath*. This is a bit complicated for a newbie and I wouldn't recommend going too deep into it until you really understand the language better; all you need to know is that anything you install with `pip`, and all of python's built-in modules and libraries, are in a certain folder on the operating system. You can put `a2.py` in that folder, too, and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you object to importing the code from a1 into a2 so you'll need the subprocess module:

```
subprocess.run(["python", "a1.py"])
```

The argument should be the path to a1.py, which can be relative or absolute.

I suggest you take a look at the module page https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Although, most of the time importing a1 into a2 will be the better solution.

Comment: wouldn't it be `subprocess.run(["python", "a1.py"])`?

Answer (score 0):

If both files are in the same directory as shown below:

```
U:\work\Python>dir
 Volume in drive U is DATA
 Volume Serial Number is FACE-76BF

 Directory of U:\work\Python

08/01/2018  11:22 AM    <DIR>          .
08/01/2018  11:22 AM    <DIR>          ..
08/01/2018  11:29 AM               470 interleave.py
07/13/2018  04:59 PM    <DIR>          LTT-Analysis
07/31/2018  04:17 PM                30 test1.py
07/31/2018  04:17 PM                37 test2.py
07/31/2018  04:18 PM    <DIR>          __pycache__
               3 File(s)          4,633 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  408,614,400,000 bytes free
```

Then you only need to import one into the other:

test1.py:

```
def foo():
    return "bar"
```

test2.py:

```
import test1
print( test1.foo() )
```

Results:

```
U:\work\Python>test2.py
bar
```